# 3 divs inside of a centered div using percentage

Tags: html, css

Good morning,

I am attempting to create a centered 3 column layout (h1, h2, h3) inside of a centered container div which has a width of 90%.

h1 and h3 are a fixed width b/c of the width of my background image and h2 should be 100% of the remainder of the space.  I'm able to make this work using specified widths but I would like to avoid that in case a user would like to view the page < 800px.

the css:

```
    #home-container {
      background-image:url('/images/bg.png');
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 800px;
    }

    #h1 {
      background-image:url('/images/navbar_left.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 27px;
    }

    #h2 {
      background-image:url('/images/navspacer.png');
      background-position: center top;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      width:746px;
    }

    #h3 {
      background-image:url('/images/navbar_right.png');
      background-position: right top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 27px;
    }

    #h1, #h2, #h3 {
      float:left;
    }
```

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>3col test</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="home-container">
        <div id="h1">1</div>
        <div id="h2">2</div>
        <div id="h3">3</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `width:auto;` for h2?

Comment: **width:auto** did not work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: another suggestion, set `float:left;` for `h1` and `h2` and `float:right;` for `h3` hah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be easier answers, but here is one way of doing it:

> Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/W8Bwe/1/

Basically, embed h1 and h3 inside h2, floated left and right respectively.

Then just set the margins on h2, to account for space taken up by h1 and h3.

Comment: This **almost** works.  My center image (navspacer) is bleeding into the left and right columns.  Trying to fix that now.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: added **margin-left: -27px** for **h1** and the opposite for **h3** and this appears to work... thanks!

Comment: ah cool - I didn't test it with a background image - never figured out how to easily get images onto jsfiddle. Glad you're sorted though.